# Trimming strings in Scala

Tags: string, scala

How do I trim the starting and ending character of a string in Scala

For inputs such as `",hello"` or  `"hello,"`, I need the output as `"hello"`.

Is there is any built-in method to do this in Scala?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Try

```
val str = "  foo  "
str.trim
```

and have a look at [the documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/StringOps.html). If you need to get rid of the `,` character, too, you could try something like:

```
str.stripPrefix(",").stripSuffix(",").trim
```

Another way to clean up the front-end of the string would be

```
val ignoreable = ", \t\r\n"
str.dropWhile(c => ignorable.indexOf(c) >= 0)
```

which would also take care of strings like `",,,  ,,hello"`

And for good measure, here's a tiny function, which does it all in one sweep from left to right through the string:

```
def stripAll(s: String, bad: String): String = {

    @scala.annotation.tailrec def start(n: Int): String = 
        if (n == s.length) ""
        else if (bad.indexOf(s.charAt(n)) < 0) end(n, s.length)
        else start(1 + n)

    @scala.annotation.tailrec def end(a: Int, n: Int): String =
        if (n <= a) s.substring(a, n)
        else if (bad.indexOf(s.charAt(n - 1)) < 0) s.substring(a, n)
        else end(a, n - 1)

   start(0)
}
```

Use like

```
stripAll(stringToCleanUp, charactersToRemove)
```

e.g.,

```
stripAll("  , , , hello , ,,,, ", " ,") => "hello"
```

Comment: @Dirk: are you sure that `tailrec` magic couldn't be replaced with with some simple regexp code? Also, `ignorable contains c` might be considered more readable.

Comment: @ErikAllik: I'm pretty sure, that all of this could have been accomplished with a regular expression (at least in this case). Besides: coming from Scheme, I actually find myself using tail-recursion a lot; I think, its a matter of habit more than anything else. The `tailrec` annotation causes the compiler to give me an error, if it cannot rewrite the code into plain loops. I find that helpful, given my predisposition to using tail recursion and the Java VM's limitations to support them properly across (e.g.) function calls.

Comment: BTW, `trim` isn't quite really documented in that documentation link provided. You'd need some solid scala-literate digging (or just experimentation) to get to what it does.

Answer (score 12):

To trim the start and ending character in a string, use a mix of drop and dropRight:

> scala> " hello,".drop(1).dropRight(1)
>
> res4: String = hello

The drop call removes the first character, dropRight removes the last.  Note that this isn't "smart" like trim is.  If you don't have any extra character at the start of "hello,", you will trim it to "ello".  If you need something more complicated, regex replacement is probably the answer.

Comment: "substring" throws java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException so you need "if" before using it - not too Scala-like

Comment: @CC thanks for the constructive criticism.  I agree that using "if" is clunky, and updated my answer to replace substring with drop() which should accomplish the same thing without risk of Exception

Comment: This is nice and simple for when you have a fixed length left and right trim.

Comment: this only works for a fixed number of characters to remove and relies on the fact the beginning and end both need trimming. this is rarely the case.

Comment: Maybe, but the OP specifically asked "How do I trim the starting and ending character of a string", not a general string trimming utility.

Comment: +1 for @lreeder - This should be an acceptable answer! More often than not, when people ask such questions, they're look for a one liner solution, not a thesis on the explanation.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to trim only commas and might have more than one on either end, you could do this:

```
str.dropWhile(_ == ',').reverse.dropWhile(_ == ',').reverse
```

The use of `reverse` here is because there is no `dropRightWhile`.

If you're looking at a single possible comma, `stripPrefix` and `stripSuffix` are the way to go, as indicated by Dirk.

Answer (score 1):

Given you only want to trim off invalid characters from the ***prefix*** and the ***suffix*** of a given string (not scan through the entire string), here's a tiny `trimPrefixSuffixChars` function to quickly perform the desired effect:

```
def trimPrefixSuffixChars(
    string: String
  , invalidCharsFunction: (Char) => Boolean = (c) => c == ' '
): String =
  if (string.nonEmpty)
    string
      .dropWhile(char => invalidCharsFunction(char))  //trim prefix
      .reverse
      .dropWhile(char => invalidCharsFunction(char)) //trim suffix
      .reverse
  else
    string
```

This function provides a default for the `invalidCharsFunction` defining only the space (" ") character as invalid. Here's what the conversion would look like for the following input strings:

```
trimPrefixSuffixChars(" Tx  ")     //returns "Tx"
trimPrefixSuffixChars(" . Tx . ")  //returns ". Tx ."
trimPrefixSuffixChars(" T x  ")    //returns "T x"
trimPrefixSuffixChars(" . T x . ") //returns ". T x ."
```

If you have you would prefer to specify your own `invalidCharsFunction` function, then pass it in the call like so:

```
trimPrefixSuffixChars(",Tx. ", (c) => !c.isLetterOrDigit)     //returns "Tx"
trimPrefixSuffixChars(" ! Tx # ", (c) => !c.isLetterOrDigit)  //returns "Tx"
trimPrefixSuffixChars(",T x. ", (c) => !c.isLetterOrDigit)    //returns "T x"
trimPrefixSuffixChars(" ! T x # ", (c) => !c.isLetterOrDigit) //returns "T x"
```

This attempts to simplify a number of the example solutions provided in other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Someone requested a regex-version, which would be something like this:

```scala
val result = " , ,, hello, ,,".replaceAll("""[,\s]+(|.*[^,\s])[,\s]+""", "'$1'")
```

Result is: `result: String = hello`

The drawback with regexes (not just in this case, but always), is that it is quite hard to read for someone who is not already intimately familiar with the syntax. The code is nice and concise, though.

Comment: This regex can also be simplified as `" , ,, hello, ,,".replaceAll("""[,\s]+""", "")`

Comment: @Grafluxe, that would also remove from the middle of the string, which is somewhat different from what the question is asking for.

Comment: Hi Pianosaurus, my logic returns the same as yours. Feel free to try it in your REPL. `val result = " , ,, hello, ,,".replaceAll("""[,\s]+""", "")` outputs `result: String = hello`
```

Comment: @Grafluxe: Only because that particular string has the characters to remove at the ends, and not in the middle. See the difference between `",he,llo,".replaceAll("""[,\s]+""", "")` and `",he,llo,".replaceAll("""[,\s]+(|.*[^,\s])[,\s]+""", "'$1'")`.

Comment: Though I removed the cruft from my answer, and wrote it using `replaceAll` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Another tailrec function:

```
def trim(s: String, char: Char): String = {
    if (s.stripSuffix(char.toString).stripPrefix(char.toString) == s)
    {
      s
    } else
    {
      trim(s.stripSuffix(char.toString).stripPrefix(char.toString), char)
    }
  }
```

```
scala> trim(",hello",',')
res12: String = hello
```

```
scala> trim(",hello,,,,",',')
res13: String = hello
```