# How can I pass in a string from XML file as a join condition for dataFrames in Spark Using Scala?

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark

I want to join dataframes, on certain columns(referred to as key), and the names of these columns are read in from an XML file.

```
private def joinTables(xmlTable : Node) {
        var key:String = (xmlTable \ "@key").text;
        println(key)
        val df1= //logic;
        val df2 = //logic;
        val join_df = df1.join(df2, Seq(key), "outer")
}
```

This is the output of println(key)

```
"col1", "col2"
```

I would hope that these two would be equivalent would look like this after passing in the key

```
val join_df = df1.join(df2, Seq("col1", "col2"), "outer") //If I hardcode and type it like this, the code runs fine
val join_df = df1.join(df2, Seq(key), "outer")
```

However, after running, I get the following error

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: USING column `"col1", "col2"` cannot be resolved on the left side of the join. The left-side columns: [col1, col2, col3, col4];
```

The XML for the key looks like so

```
 <table name="table1" key="&quot;col1&quot;, &quot;col2&quot;, &quot;col3&quot;, &quot;col4&quot;">
</table>
```

I get the same error even if I modify the above xml so the key is only one column

```
<table name="table1" key="&quot;col1&quot;">
    </table>
```

Error Message:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:  USING column `"col1"` cannot be resolved on the left side of the join. The left-side columns: [col1, col2, col3, col4];
```

To summarize:
How can I read in a String from XML and use it to join two dataframes using Scala? Is my approach incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

The value you're getting from the XML file and stored in `key` is a single string.

```
var key:String = (xmlTable \ "@key").text;
```

That's not a list of strings, it's a single string.  To make a sequence of columns, you need to use `split` and various strip functions.

```
val cols = key.split(", ").map(_.stripPrefix("\"").stripSuffix("\""))
```

These are covered in the following previous questions.

[Trimming strings in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995260/trimming-strings-in-scala)

[How to split a string by a string in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522572/how-to-split-a-string-by-a-string-in-scala)