# lstrip and rstrip non blank character from string

Tags: scala

How do you strip characters (not necessarily white space i.e. blanks) from the start and end of a String in Scala?

The Python analogue to what I am looking for is `lstrip` and `rstrip`.

This is the desired functionality:

```
ltrim("{blah blah}", "{") should equal("blah blah}")
ltrim("blah blah", "{") should equal("blah blah") // no exception

rtrim("blah blah}", "}") should equal("blah blah")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stripSuffix` and `stripPrefix`

This is a closely related question: [Trimming strings in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995260/trimming-strings-in-scala)

Documentation links:

https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.6/scala/collection/immutable/StringLike.html#stripPrefix(prefix:String):String

https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.6/scala/collection/immutable/StringLike.html#stripSuffix(suffix:String):String

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`dropWhile`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html#dropWhile(p:A=%3EBoolean):Repr) if you want to remove a specific character from the beginning of a `String`:

```
"{{blah blah}".dropWhile(_ == '{')
// "blah blah}"
```

This drops any character from the left of the `String` which fulfills the given predicate which in this case is being equal to the character to remove.

---

In order to remove a character from the right, since there is not yet a `dropWhileRight` equivalent in the standard library, one way could consist in a double reverse:

```
"{{blah blah}".reverse.dropWhile(_ == '}').reverse
// {{blah blah
```

or slightly more efficients:

```
"{{blah blah}}".dropRight("{{blah blah}}".reverse.segmentLength(_ == '}'))
// {{blah blah
"{{blah blah}}".stripSuffix("{{blah blah}}".reverse.takeWhile(_ == '}'))
// {{blah blah
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions functions

```
scala> "{blah blah}".replaceAll("""^[{]+""","")
res35: String = blah blah}

scala> "{{blah blah}".replaceAll("""^[{]+""","")
res36: String = blah blah}

scala> "blah blah}".replaceAll("""^[{]+""","")
res37: String = blah blah}

scala> "blah blah}".replaceAll("""[}]+$""","")
res38: String = blah blah

scala>
```